# Spring Boot v2.0 doesn't see template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I try to launch demo application created in [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io). Spring Boot version - 2.0.3.

I created index.html and placed it into `resources/templates` folder. When I launch `spring-boot:run`, one of messages in console states:

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

And when I open `localhost:8080`, it gives me Spring's Whitelabel Error Page

I tried to add line `server.servlet.context-path=/`at `resources/application.properties` file. But it doesn't help.

How can I set a correct path for index?

UPD: Seems like the problem is only with template part.

Contents of `index.html` in `resources/templates`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
<h1>Hello {{ name }}!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of `IndexController.java`:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("name", "world");
        return new ModelAndView("index", model);
    }
```

I use mustache, in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

And it gives me whitelabel error. Even with `server.servlet.context-path=/` in `resources/application.properties`

If I place file in `resource/static`, and rename file to "index.html" in `IndexController`, it is shown, but "name" is obviously not replaced.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037193/5493734) helped. Seems that it's mustache feature. That's strange, because with SpringBoot 1.5.x everything works fine with empty file `application.properties`. If someone knows, why it changed for SpringBoot 2.0 - share in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve static content, you need to put it into the `static` folder in your `resources` folder.

`templates` is used when you're using view technology like Thymeleaf and Spring MVC controllers.

You can find more information here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: I use mustache templating engine. Anyway, after moving my `index.html` to `static`folder I got the same result

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot directs the request to the matching controller. Thus, define a simple Controller class to handle the request and place that class in a package below or inside your project's root-package:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @GetMapping(value={"/"})
   public ModelAndView getRoot()
   {
       return new ModelAndView("index");
   }
}
```

The Controller-Annotation comes from package org.springframework.stereotype and the GetMapping-Annotation from org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.

Maybe you also need to extend your pom.xml file. Check if it contains the dependency spring-boot-starter-web (if you has choosen 'Maven Project').

Comment: I have a controller. IDE imports packages mentioned by you, and pom file contains this dependency. Still, nothing works, and I guess, it's because context path not set to "\". But I don't know how to set it correctly, as `application.property` file doesn't help

Comment: The output " with context path '' " should not bother you. That's what it says by default. Feel free to change the context root by setting server.servlet.context-path in your application.properties file (for older versions of spring boot use server.context-path). But I don't see a problem here (just checked a few of my microservices: they all say " with context path '' " and work fine).

Comment: Yu can also change the Mapping to a list of values. Feel free to try @GetMapping(value{"/", ""})

Comment: Aha, I found something. It shows page only if I give "index.html" instead of "index" to ModelAndView constructor . And it doesn't replace {{ var }} by var value from map given to constructor. I guess, there is something wrong with templates... I use `spring-boot-starter-mustache` from tutorial...I don't know

Comment: Updated question. @Flocke, can you check?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Mustache, nonetheless I noticed one detail: You don't have to add a HashMap as Model to the ModelAndView-object. You can simply create a M&V-Object  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index"); and after that add objects by calling mv.addObject("objectName", object); Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should change application.properties

```
spring.mustache.suffix:.html
```